# Error when trying to mount windows share

Tags: 11.04, mount, automount

I am able to view my share if I write the following

```
nautilus smb://privatenas
```

[image]

This open the shares on privatenas (C, home)

If I try the following

```
nautilus smb://privatenas/home
```

it opens a login window that asks for domain admin username and password.

Everything is fine, but what I am trying to do, is mount smb://privatenas/home to /home/administrator/PRIVATENAS

I have tried the regular mount command:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs //privatenas/home /home/administrator/privatenas -o uid=1000
```

But that gives me an error: asks for a password.

What am I missing?
What am I doing wrong?

Using the following

```
smbclient -L //192.168.0.25 -U administrator
```

That gives me a list of the smb shares. I want to mount one of them.

```
administrator@optitexfog:~$ smbclient -L //privatenas
```

Enter administrator's password:

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (PRIVATENAS)
c               Disk      Volume C
home            Disk      Private user folders
administrator   Disk      Private user folder

Server               Comment
---------            -------
OPTITEXDC            
PRIVATENAS           PRIVATENAS

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
OPTITEX              OPTITEXDC
administrator@optitexfog:~$
```

I thought I had it sorted, but I can't see my files.

OK, I have a feeling, that this is NOT a real windows share. The reason I suspect this is that if I browse to \192.168.0.25\ I will NOT see the home folder.

OK, now, my last findings are sad. In order to test my theory, I created a test Share on my NAS. The mount command worked like a breeze.
So, the //PRIVATENAS/home is NOT a real Windows share, or at least, not a share I can mount. This does not look correct to me.
What should I check?
As mentioned, I have a ReadyNAS, netgear 1100 with Raidiator 4.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the username at your command. It should be something like this:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs -o username=saariko,uid=1000 //privatenas/home /home/administrator/privatenas
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that. I get error : permission denied. I tried to use the admin user of the NAS (admin) not sure what username is needed.

Comment: Check the configuration of your NAS. There should be a user and a password set for the samba access.

Comment: It's the same you have used with Nautilus.